# Concat variables in Heredoc

Tags: string, shell, variables, concatenation, ksh

I have the following KornShell (ksh) script:

```
VAR='/this/is/a/path/'
DAT='01_01_2014'

cat << EOF
... what should I do here to concat variables with strings? ...
$VARfoldername$DAT
EOF
```

Howerver, this gives me only (because the variable $VARfoldername is evaluated, which apparently does not exist):

```
01_01_2014
```

I need to concat $VAR with another string and then with $DAT, such that running the script results in:

```
/this/is/a/path/foldername01_01_2014
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

shell has just the syntax for you:

```
${VAR}foldername${DAT}
```

IHTH